# how to restyle or move google-revocation-link-placeholder

Tags: adsense, gdprconsentform

I inserted Google's GDPR messaging in my site. Unfortunately, it ads a div with class="google-revocation-link-placeholder" that is supposed to go in the footer but gets placed apparently randomly in the page.
I could not find any info on this class in Google Adsense documentation and only one reference in a google search, with no answers.
Is there a way to move it to a predefined position?

I tried with jquery once the page gets loaded, but unfortunately the function is triggered too early in the rendition process so has no effect.

[example of wrong placement of the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKS6H.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mutation observer to remove the element from the DOM.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  document.querySelector(".google-revocation-link-placeholder")?.remove();
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
});
```

You should probably add a [revocation link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10959060) to the page to remain compliant though.

Comment: Is this method OK with Google?

Answer (score -1):

```
javascript:googlefc.callbackQueue.push(googlefc.showRevocationMessage)
```

A revocation link from google support doesn't work.

Comment: What does your post even mean ?

Comment: @adrianTNT https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10114217

Comment: You mean that custom link to change current approval options ? I added that link code in footer at https://www.apkfiles.com and it worked nicely. I am on mobile, cannot paste the code.

Comment: This one worked: `javascript:googlefc.callbackQueue.push(googlefc.showRevocationMessage)`